# Confusion related to Armijo's rule

Tags: convex-optimization

I am having confusion related to Armijo's rule used for line search. Can you give me some links to good tutorials. I want to get the geometric interpretation behind it. I found this one http://tosca.cs.technion.ac.il/book/samples/optimization_5_3.pdf but it is not clear still

Answer (score 0):

This link might help, it's a similar question.

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/confusion-about-armijo-rule

And here is a lecture.
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-093j-optimization-methods-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT15_093J_F09_lec19.pdf